# How to combine columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i combine different column in the select command, and also insert some special characters like @,- etc.

columns are date,home team, away team. i want this in below format:

12-36 awayteam @ hometeam.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use concatenation available with select.

```
SELECT home_score || '-' || away_score || ' ' ||  home || ' @ ' ||  away as Result
FROM Score
```

**Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE Score
(
   home        varchar(20),
   away        varchar(20),
   home_score  integer,
   away_score  integer
);
```

Comment: thats wonderful, i got it

Comment: One more question can we change the data type while pulling out the data, i mean with select command.

Comment: could you elaborate your question?

Comment: @user1087354 Yes you can. Describe what you have and what you want to convert it to.